# Laravel validator returns $error as empty and old input also not coming

Tags: laravel

Here is My Code:

Model(User.php)

```
 public static function validate($data)
{
    return validator::make($data,  static::$rules);
}
```

Route

```
Route::post('sign_up',['as'=>'sign_up','uses'=>function(){
$validate = App\User::validate(Input::all());
 if($validate->fails())
   {

     return Redirect::back()->with_errors($validate)->withInput();
     }
   dd(Input::all());
  }]);
```

View:

```
     @if (count($errors) > 0)
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        @endif
```

Here iam getting errors as empty and also i am missing my old inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of laravel framework you are using ?

once replace this line of code :-

```
return Redirect::back()->with_errors($validate)->withInput();
```

with this following code and give a try:-

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Anup GC.I had wasted a lot of time for this as per your method it works now i am gettting the errors.but i was missing my old inputs.i am not getting the old inputs can u pls help me for that also

Comment: i also got the old input.once again thank you for your support